# Extract the contents with the help of a regular expression

Tags: php, regexp-replace

there is a string of the form

'[Text1] text2 - text3' or 'text2 - text3'
that is, sometimes there [text1] in square brackets, and sometimes not. and always before text2 is '-'

that need to be trimmed and php means stay only 'text2'

example:

> [Tim sausage] For Anubis - Conqueror - a staunch defender
>
> Overwrath - commented Head
>
> Warpatch Hemos - Began "fever"

should get

```
For Anubis
Overwrath
Warpatch Hemos
```

Answer (score 0):

try do something like this:

```
$arr = array(
    '[Tim sausage] For Anubis - Conqueror - a staunch defender',
    'Overwrath - commented Head',
    'Warpatch Hemos - Began "fever"'
);

foreach($arr as $v)
{
    $v = preg_replace("!\[.*\]!", '', $v);
    $v = preg_replace("!\-.*!", '', $v);
    echo $v.'<br/>;
}
```